# How to decrease the building time for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, build-time

I am working on solution with 40+ projects interlinked together.

At the moment, the build time is ~30min, and I really want to shorten it. What would be a good place to start shortening the build time?

Some background: I don't know much about the setup of the solution, but we have a lot of linking to do (to encryption, codec libraries and between projects).

The whole size of the project is ~2.7 GB, then we are also linking it to Boost C++, Intel IPP 7

Please help pointing me in a good direction.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 in C++ build time reduction is more memory. After switching from 4GB to 12GB, I saw my link-all-projects time fall off a cliff: from 5:50 to 1:15.